# Styling iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any possibility to style iframe content ?

I am working on Google integration and including iframe with document.

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FXbO5XkM5jIcvkqNTEu2EoxmU9UmlyLaa8NPmlcQW1M"></iframe>
```

This google document has Menu(File, Edit ...) which i dont want to be displayed. Is there any possibility to target this elements and give them attributes such as . Display:none ? Or simply hide this elements somehow ?

Thanks !

Comment: I would have to go with No, it is not possible unless the iframe is being included into a document that exists on the https://docs.google.com domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, as you said **somehow**,

you could try:

```
<div id="trick">
   <iframe/>
</div>

#trick{
   overflow:hidden; /* you will have to play a bit with heights and widths*/
}
#trick iframe{
   position:absolute; /*or relative. depending on your markup*/
   top:-90px /* Asuming the menu you want to hide is that height */
}
```

'Seems' to do the job: http://jsfiddle.net/Tey5f/3/

or you could:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('head').append('rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myChanges.css" />');
```

Comment: nice trick, does the job! you should use relative position instead, in case you want to have other content on the page. the second part of your answer would violate cross-domain policy though.

Comment: Nice trick ! I ve just configure it a little and it does the job ! thanks again :)

Comment: It seems you are not actually allowed to append anything into the iFrame. Oh, well.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to apply styles to an external site like Google Docs, cross-domain prevention.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. However, you could use proxy to load google's content :) Once you configured your server side to proxy such request just replace googles urls with something like this:

```
http://yoursite.com/googleproxy/document/d/1FXbO5XkM5jIcvkqNTEu2EoxmU9UmlyLaa8NPmlcQW1M
```

But there may be problems with the content linked by that googles page, because now requests to `docs.google.com` are cross-domain.