# styling elements inside an iframe

Tags: css, iframe

I am having trouble styling contents inside an Iframe. I can't change this, I don't know why it was build this way, but I need to be able to style some divs with css inside the iframe.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: content inside iframe will be styling according to css files loaded in document that is requested by url in iframe, not from css files of parent page

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS to iFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

content inside iframe will be styling according to css files loaded in document that is requested by url in iframe, not from css files of parent page

Comment: Cairo, can I then relink to the same css file in the root html?

Comment: if you want to load same css file in both pages parent and child in iframe, no technical issue for this

Comment: here is what I am trying. <script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content').load(function(){
    var timestamp =  +(new Date());
    $('#content').contents().find('head').append('<link href="http://photographyforachange.com/newsite/wp-content/themes/photocrati-theme/styles/iframe.css?'+ timestamp +'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
  });
});
</script>

Comment: the problem is not in your js code, if you are loading page2 in iframne successfully, go to page2 html and put meta tage of css file there.

Comment: thanks, got it. Was trying to do it with jquery, but was just as easy to go to iframe code. UGH. I hate editing themes.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the Same Origin Policy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Due to security reasons, you aren't allowed to manipulate an external website's code within an iframe.

Comment: same server, I have no idea why I frames were used.

Comment: As long as it's the same domain, try one of the methods from this top answer to see if it works for you: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321653/styling-iframe-content)